# How to put background color for one tab inside QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

Can somebody help me color the tab inside `QTabWidget`? I know that there are a lot of questions asked about it, but none I could find helpful to me. The reason why I am struggling is that I have `QTabWidget` > there are two tabs "one" and "two" > and there is one more tab inside tab "one" called "test". I want to have color on a tab called "one". I know it's a little bit confusing reading it like that, but I hope you can understand better from the code.
Here is a code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt4 demo')
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.createTabs()
        self.show()

    def createTabs(self):
        self.tabs.resize(1000, 1000)

        contents1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        contents2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        contents1.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        contents1.setLayout(contents1.layout)

        self.tabs.addTab(contents1, 'one')
        contents1.setStyleSheet('QTabBar::tab {background-color: red;}')

        self.tabs.addTab(contents2, 'two')

        extra_tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        extra_tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        extra_tab_widget.addTab(extra_tab, 'test')
        contents1.layout.addWidget(extra_tab_widget)



def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

I tried giving color to contents1, but it gives color on the tab inside that tab called "test" instead of giving it on the tab "one". I tried putting `setStyleSheets` on `QTabWidget`, but then it's coloring everything. Does anybody know a solution, hopefully using `setStyleSheet`? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's a bit confusing. What do you want to color? The "tab" or the contents (the "page" that is displayed when that tab is selected)? Because, in the first case, it's almost impossible just with stylesheets, except for the *only* situation for which that tab is the first (or last). On the other hand, you should use `self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)`.

Comment: I want a tab with the name "one" to make red color and nothing else

Comment: The only way is to use the [`::tab` subcontrol](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#tab-sub) along with the object name selector. By the way, the stylesheet must be set on the tab widget, not on the widget used as contents of the tab. `self.tabs.setObjectName('mainTabWidget')` `self.tabs.setStyleSheet('QTabWidget#mainTabWidget > QTabBar::tab:first {background: yellow;}')`. Note: you can only style the first, the last or selected/deselected tabs, you cannot style specific tabs (such as based on the index or name).

Answer (score 0):

I like to style using an external file. Then with the setQss() function I apply the styles.
In [customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar) ... you can find styling examples.
To facilitate the activity, you can use setObjectName()

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabs.setObjectName('tab_1')
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt4 demo')
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.createTabs()
        self.show()

    def createTabs(self):
        self.tabs.resize(1000, 1000)
        contents1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        contents1.setObjectName('cont_1')
        contents2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        contents2.setObjectName('cont_2')
        contents1.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        contents1.setLayout(contents1.layout)
        self.tabs.addTab(contents1, 'one')
        #contents1.setStyleSheet('QTabBar::tab {background-color: red;}')
        self.tabs.addTab(contents2, 'two')
        extra_tab_widget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        extra_tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        extra_tab_widget.addTab(extra_tab, 'test')
        contents1.layout.addWidget(extra_tab_widget)

def setQss(_app, _qss):
    File = QtCore.QFile(_qss)
    if not File.open( QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
        return

    qss = QtCore.QTextStream(File)
    _app.setStyleSheet(qss.readAll())


def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    setQss(app, "style.qss")
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

The style.qss file:

```
#tab_1 QTabBar::tab {
    background-color: yellow;       
}

#tab_1 QTabBar::tab:selected{
    background-color: black;    
}

#cont_1 QTabBar::tab {
    background-color: red;
}

#cont_1 QTabBar::tab:selected{
    background-color: pink; 
}

#cont_1{
    background-color: green;
}

#cont_2{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it, thanks! But sadly it's not exactly fit me. I will have to do a lot of work around to make this work in my case, I believe. Because I am trying to make the program that will change the colors of tabs, I need it to be callable anytime with the color I put as an argument. That's why I wanted to use "setStyleSheet". With your method I am afraid I would have to write a function that will find and replace lines in a qss file, which also is fine, but I would like to try to avoid overcomplicating this process.